# Where to find a polygon database of golf courses in the US?

Tags: data, point-of-interest

Does anyone know where I can find an accurate polygon database of all golf courses in the us?

Comment: [Golfbert.com](http://golfbert.com) is releasing an API for their golf course maps database, which includes polygons for every green, fairway, hazard and tee box. I think you can possibly get in their BETA group by emailing dave@golfbert.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [POI Factory](http://www.poi-factory.com/).  They have a [Golf Courses-USA dataset](http://www.poi-factory.com/node/29395) that apparently originated from [www.golflinks.com](http://www.golflinks.com).

You should of course read into their [Terms of Use](http://www.poi-factory.com/terms) policy to make sure your use case is covered.

Answer (score 1):

The 05 ESRI StreetMap lyr file contains about 7100 golf course polygons nation-wide.  However this most likely is a small sample of all the courses that may exist.

Answer (score 1):

Google Earth has fairly complete data set of these, it's only a viewer though. I remember a few years ago seeing a GIS job with golflink.com, might try contacting them and see if they share / sell their data sets [image: Google Earth gold course layer]

Comment: Can you export a layer from Google Earth?

Answer (score 1):

try [Geodeg](http://geodeg.com)

8852 golf courses in USA
http://geodeg.com/search.php?q=golf+course&language=&country=220

Answer (score 0):

I don't think every data dream can come to reality.

If there's an agency which does not have a vision to manage geo-spatial information for itself, getting such a data can be a tedious task.

You can get the textual information very easily, but finding a GIS data can be (almost) impossible.

See the [Golf Directory](http://www.golflink.com/golf-courses/course-directory.aspx)...

Answer (score 0):

Overpass, which takes data from Open Street Map, should get you the data you need. It can be used for just about any inquiry regarding physical map areas.

http://overpass-turbo.eu/

Keys and Values: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_features#Power

Just type this into the Overpass Wizard, replacing your desired area for AREA IN DOUBLE QUOTES.

leisure=golf_course in "AREA IN DOUBLE QUOTES"